# How to prove that the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}{\frac{\mathrm{d}\xi}{\left(1+||\xi||\right)^s}}$ converges?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, indefinite-integrals

How to prove that the integral $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}{\frac{\mathrm{d}\xi}{\left(1+||\xi||\right)^s}}$$ converges when $s>N$? Can somebody compute it?

Comment: Do you know how to do it for $N=1$? I will also look for a duplicate on the site, I suspect there is one given it is quite a common question as an exercise.

Comment: Depending on the norm, you can probably do some sort of coordinate substitution (which preserves convergence for integrals with positive integrand). The most natural one could be polar coordinates if this is the Euclidean norm. In general, you can integrate on the unit sphere of the norm, which is doable for some other simple norms – $\ell^1$ and $\ell^{\infty}$, for instance.